# get only numbers in a list after crawling from the web

Tags: python, list, xpath, scrapy, extract

I want to extract only numbers from this list, and at the same time return their average.

Can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: I want to modify the crawling code so that the data I get directly from the web is exactly in the expected form (average number).

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rating(row):
    return float(row.split(None, 2)[1])

star_nums = [rating(row) for row in star]
star_avg = sum(star_nums) / len(star_nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = []
for txt in star:
    nums += float(txt.split()[1]),
```

Comment: I want to modify the code which crawls the data so that I can just get numbers from the web.